# Variable not parsed inside other variable definition

Tags: elisp, variables, quote

I want to store the credentials for posting to my blog secret. Therefore I load them using [EasyPG](http://epg.sourceforge.jp/) and put them in the variables `blog-username` and `blog-password`.

When I show the content of those vars using `C-h v blog-username` (`describe-variable`) the values are correct.

However when I set the `wp-blog-alist` value those values seem to not be parsed. This is the error message:

> xml-rpc-value-to-xml-list: Wrong type argument: stringp,
>   blog-username

Here is how I use the function.

```
(setq
 org2blog/wp-confirm-post t
 org2blog/wp-blog-alist
 '(
   ("0xcb0"
    :url "http://www.my_blog_address.com/xmlrpc.php"
    :username blog-username
    :password blog-password
    :default-title "Hello, World!"
    :default-categories ("Uncategorized")
    :tags-as-categories nil)
    ))
```

What syntax do I need to use inside the second `setq`for `org2blog/wp-blog-alist` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote (`'`) causes the following expression to be not evaluated, therefore `blog-username` and `blog-password` are not evaluated to their string values, but instead taken as symbols.

One way of getting around this is using the `list` function to explicitly quote symbols when necessary (note that the colon automatically quotes keywords):

```
(setq
 org2blog/wp-confirm-post t
 org2blog/wp-blog-alist
 (list (list "0xcb0"
             :url "http://www.my_blog_address.com/xmlrpc.php"
             :username blog-username
             :password blog-password
             :default-title "Hello, World!"
             :default-categories (list "Uncategorized")
             :tags-as-categories nil)))
```

The other option is using the backquote construct (```) and selectively unquote (`,`) values you want to be exempt from quoting:

```
(setq
 org2blog/wp-confirm-post t
 org2blog/wp-blog-alist
 `(("0xcb0"
    :url "http://www.my_blog_address.com/xmlrpc.php"
    :username ,blog-username
    :password ,blog-password
    :default-title "Hello, World!"
    :default-categories ("Uncategorized")
    :tags-as-categories nil)))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that solved it! In my opinion I find the second option to be more readable.